# Cell Label text overlapping in cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am attempting to add a `UILabel`to my `collectionViewCell`. However, after a few cell text begins to overlap with data from the cells before.

**UPDATE**: This only seems to happen on my phone (iphone 5), but not on the simulator (2013 macbook air).

As seen here:

[image]

I am implementing the whole view programmatically. The issue doesn't seem to be with any of the elements of the `collectionview`, so I would assume the problem applies to table views as well. I am not sure if I am missing something along the lines of:

```
if(cell == nil) {// do something }
```

If it is that, can someone shed some light on what this does? If that's not the issue I am really not sure what is causing this. I am also using an `NSMutableAttributedString`, but that is not the issue either as I tried to insert just a regular string  and got the same results.

My code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    TTSong *tempSong = [songArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UILabel *cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 110, 150, 40)];
    [cellLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [cellLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8]];
    [cellLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Light" size: 12.0f]];
    [cellLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
    NSString * labelString = [[tempSong.artist stringByAppendingString:@"\n"] stringByAppendingString:tempSong.title];
    NSMutableAttributedString * attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:labelString];
    NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(0, tempSong.artist.length);
    [attributedString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0f] range:boldedRange];
    [cellLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
    [cell addSubview:cellLabel];

    return cell;
}
```

Here is how I set the size of the cells:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(150, 150);
}
```

Here is how I setup my `collectionView`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    songArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    _collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];

    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: Cells are reused, and your code will add another cellLabel to a reused cell that already has one. If you're going to add labels in code this way, then you need to check if the cell already has one before you add another.

Comment: Thanks. So if the cell already has a label, I need to clear it out first?

Is there a better way of implementing this? Can you spot anymore bad practices from that code?

Comment: You could clear it, or just check if there is one, and don't add another if there is. Other ways to do this would be to create the cell with its label in the storyboard (that's the easiest way imo) , or create a custom class, and add the label in its init method.

Comment: I've done it the storyboard way, just trying to do a project without them. I fixed the issues by assigned the label a tag, checking if it exists in the cell and removing it from the cell if it does before assigning a new one. 

Can you expand on what you mean by "cells are reused"? I guess I am missing something on the way that the collectionview is implemented.

Comment: If you don't understand cell reuse (for table views and collection views) then you should read Apple's documents on those classes, because its a fundamental feature of the way they work. Basically, only the number of cells needed to be displayed on the screen at any one time are created. When you scroll one off the top, it goes into a reuse pool, and it is used for the one that comes in from the bottom. Any subviews it has will still be there, and so will any label strings, etc., so you need to overwrite all the data in the cell to be appropriate for its new row position.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the label and reinitialize it when cell is display.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    TTSong *tempSong = [songArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    for (UILabel *lbl in cell.contentView.subviews)
    {
        if ([lbl isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
        {
            [lbl removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    UILabel *cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 110, 150, 40)];
    [cellLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [cellLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8]];
    [cellLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Light" size: 12.0f]];
    [cellLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
    NSString * labelString = [[tempSong.artist stringByAppendingString:@"\n"] stringByAppendingString:tempSong.title];
    NSMutableAttributedString * attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:labelString];
    NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(0, tempSong.artist.length);
    [attributedString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0f] range:boldedRange];
    [cellLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
    [cell addSubview:cellLabel];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I ended up using tags to remove the label.

Comment: Working great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to tick the "clears graphic context" property of the label in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Cells are already has the elements and also you creating(Adding) the labels by programmatically.

What you have to do is :

**1 .Remove the UILabels within the UITableViewCell in the UIStoryBoard && create Programmatically.**

```
   - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        TTSong *tempSong = [songArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    UILabel *cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 110, 150, 40)];
        [cellLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [cellLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8]];
        [cellLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Light" size: 12.0f]];
        [cellLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
        NSString * labelString = [[tempSong.artist stringByAppendingString:@"\n"] stringByAppendingString:tempSong.title];
        NSMutableAttributedString * attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:labelString];
        NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(0, tempSong.artist.length);
        [attributedString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0f] range:boldedRange];
        [cellLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
        [cell addSubview:cellLabel];
    
        return cell;
    }
```

*OR*

**2.Add the UILabel's in the storyboard and use the reference of it && Don't create in the code just refer(point) it**.

Use the **Tag** property to point on the elements.

```
  - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        TTSong *tempSong = [songArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    UILabel *cellLabel = (UILabel*)[cell ViewWithTag:25];
        [cellLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [cellLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8]];
        [cellLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Light" size: 12.0f]];
        [cellLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
        NSString * labelString = [[tempSong.artist stringByAppendingString:@"\n"] stringByAppendingString:tempSong.title];
        NSMutableAttributedString * attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:labelString];
        NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(0, tempSong.artist.length);
        [attributedString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0f] range:boldedRange];
        [cellLabel setAttributedText:attributedString];
      //  [cell addSubview:cellLabel]; Don't add this again
    
        return cell;
    }
```